# cURL timeout on heroku - PHP

Tags: php, curl, heroku

what i need to do it's load a php page output, into an variable. What i tryed:

**CURL:**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => "$url",
));
$output = curl_exec($curl);
```

**FILE GET CONTENTS**

```
$output = file_get_contents($url);
```

The problem it's that the request it's to the same server, like:

**http://www.example.com.br/page1.php**

trying to get output from

**http://www.example.com.br/page2.php**

so it doesnt work. If i try to put an external server, works fine. Tried on other servers, and locally, and works fine. But on heroku, doesn't work. Give's me an H12 error, TIMEOUT.

```
code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/data.php/mailmkt/email" 
host=xxxxxxx request_id=xxxxx fwd="xx.xx.xx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms 
service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

What i can do? saw other people having this problem, but no solution yet.

I'm using **heroku-php-nginx** buildpack, but **apache2** doesnt work too, i tried.

Edit:
Saw now that the error just occurs if I'm using nodejs builpack with php buildpack. If using just php buildpack, works fine.

Comment: Try using the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` options to increase the timeouts and see whether the problem still occurs

Comment: @JamieBicknell Tryed that. It doesnt work. Saw now that the error just occurs if I'm using nodejs builpack with php buildpack. If using just php buildpack, works fine.